# Mutualise two different data into one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, coalesce

I have an assignment as part of my Master's program, and I have a question regarding data processing in R.
I have two different data frames that convey the same information but are normally associated with different individuals.
I would like to merge these two data frames into one data frame to have a single variable to work with. The variables that need to overlap are either NA in one data set or in the other.
The first thing I would like to verify is whether, when merging, there are only NA values and no other values that could be overwritten.
The second thing is how to perform this merge.
The data format is a data frame, which I extracted from a much larger dataset (Swiss Household Panel).
Do you have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

In the provided Drive link dwon bellow, you will find the two data files. Thank you in advance!

The two R files:

1. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bP3kFqn-U9Y3D3z06dN7k9B1Gu9MJ87h/view?usp=sharing
2. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zn-liT33Q0YcXvRKkT06TxxyMIb71dNy/view?usp=sharing

I have tried to delete the NA values in both data set and the merge them afterward but it didnt'worked.

I have also tried the function coalesce(cc01,c01) and melt(list(c01, cc01)) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please practice giving us a **minimal** reproducible example - you could have put an example with 10 rows directly into your question, rather than posting two 1-MB files for download ...

Answer (score -1):

This might work:

```r
## extract variables from data frames, convert to character (combining
##   factors with different levels may be dicey)
c01x <- as.character(c01[[1]])
cc01x <- as.character(cc01[[1]])

results <- ifelse(is.na(c01x) & is.na(cc01x),
                   NA,  ## if both are NA result is NA
           ifelse(is.na(c01x), cc01x,   ## if c01 is NA then we want cc01
           c01x))                       ## and vice versa
```

The result will be a character vector, which you can make back into a factor and/or put back into a data frame if you like.

You might want to consider what should happen if there are any observations where *neither* input is `NA` ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked well. I've also added code to consider neither input is NA.

`results <- ifelse(is.na(c01x) & is.na(cc01x),
                  NA,  ## if both are NA result is NA
                  ifelse(is.na(c01x), cc01x,   ## if c01 is NA then we want cc01
                         c01x,
                  ifelse(is.character(c01x)==is.character(cc01x),is.character(c01x),
                  ifelse(is.character(c01x)&is.character(cc01x),"ERROR"))
covid<-data.frame(results)`